# Space homotopy equivalent to its own suspension is contractible

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Suppose that a path-connected CW complex $X$ is homotopy equivalent to its own suspension $SX$. Is it true that $X$ must be contractible?

I have tried to show that since $X \times I \simeq SX = X \times I /\! \sim$, the projection $X \times I \to X \times \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ induces a projection $X \times I /\! \sim\; \to \lbrace x_0 \rbrace \times \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ such that $X \times \lbrace 0 \rbrace \simeq \lbrace x_0 \rbrace \times \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ as desired, but this does not seem to be successful or [true in general](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3717770/restriction-of-a-homotopy-equivalence).

Edit: Following freakish's comment, by the Freudenthal suspension theorem and Whitehead's theorem, this is true. Might a more elementary proof be possible? (I don't think so, but I'd be pleasantly surprised if there was one.)

Comment: It is true for CW complex by combination of Freudenthal (all homotopy groups have to be trivial) and Whitehead (so it is contractible). But outside of CW I wouldn't expect much.

Comment: @freakish Just to be clear: Suppose $X$ is $n$-connected. By Freudenthal, $\pi_{n+1}(X) \cong \pi_{n+1}(SX) \cong \pi_n(X) = 0$. We can then argue inductively, assuming $X$ is $0$-connected in the first place, correct?

Comment: Yes. And it is $0$-connected, because every suspension is.

Comment: My original motivation for this question was an exercise in Hatcher: Show that $S^\infty$, with its usual CW structure, is contractible. It seems that this was not the intended method of proof!

Comment: Since $X$ is naturally a subspace of $SX$, a less general but perhaps more answerable question could be: "Is $X$ contractible if $X\hookrightarrow SX$ is a homotopy equivalence?" [As for the Hatcher exercise...](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4602576) (several of the "proofs" there are wrong, see the end for correct stuff with precise hypotheses)

Comment: The intended solution by Hatcher is likely the one I refer to somewhere in my link, where we inductively define a deformation. A lot of the fluff in the link is about trying to generalise it, but in the specific case we're good

Comment: $X\simeq SX\simeq S^2X\simeq ...S^\infty X=\star$

Comment: @BobDobbs do you have a reference for the last step? Also I would question jf there are any hypotheses needed to promote a homotopy equivalence to a one on the colimit

Comment: @FShrike (I work in the reduced setting.) It is enough to suppose that $\{\ast\}\rightarrow X$ is a closed cofibration and $X\subseteq SX$ a (pointed) h-equivalence. You obtain a "ladder" with top row $SX\subseteq S^2X\subseteq\dotsc$ and bottom row $X=X=\dotsc$ and vertical maps all (pointed) h-equivalences and horizontal maps all cofibrations, which implies the colimit $X\subseteq S^{\infty}X$ is a (pointed) h-equivalence. On the other hand, it is not too hard to show that a colimit of pointed nullhomotopic cofibrations such as $S^{\infty}X$ deformation retracts to its basepoint.

Comment: If, however, we merely assume an abstract h-equivalence $X\simeq SX$, I'm not sure if that allows to deduce much. If $X$ is well-pointed as before, appealing to Freudenthal still yields that it is weakly contractible (and for that it would suffice to assume that $X$ and $SX$ are weakly equivalent, even), but I don't see contractibility lurking in sight.

Comment: @FShrike No reference. Oops  It is not equal.... I dont know colinit.

Answer (score 1):

**remark:** you don't need any of this.

Making a few assumptions rather than abstract isomorphisms might help.

Suppose that $X$ is connected and a cw-complex. Also suppose that the natural map $X \to CX/X=\Sigma X$ induces a weak equivalence.

Instead of freudenthal suspension (which is sort of hardcore) we can use Van-Kampen's theorem to show that $X$ is simply connected.

Then the Hurewicz theorem improves Whitehead's theorem so that a homology equivalence is enough.

from the long exact sequence we get an exact sequence
$ \cdots \to \tilde{H_n}(X) \to \tilde{H}_n(CX) \to \tilde{H}_n(\Sigma X) \to \cdots$

Now the composite of the first two maps is assumed to be an isomorphism but factors through zero, so in fact $\tilde{H_n}(X)=0$ and this isomorphism is induced by the inclusion  $X \to CX$.

This suffices for your question on contractibility of $S^\infty$, but there are much easier proofs using left and right shift operators.

Comment: I think the Freudenthal suspensión theorem is as hardcore as the Hurewicz theorem (both are consequences of Blackers-Massey theorem)

Comment: Also, proving that the natural inclusion is nullhomotopic is immediate, since it factors through the cone,  which is contractible. You don't need homology for that.

Comment: you absolutely do not need blakers-massey to show the hurewicz theorem, although the proof of freudenthal is basically the same as blakers massey. Anyway that's a matter of taste. I don't think I used anything about homology to show that the inclusion is nullhomotopic.

Comment: You can derive both Freudenthal and Hurewicz from Blakers-Massey, but neither is as strong as the latter (also, historically, Blakers-Massey was first proven in the early 50s whereas the other two were proven in the mid-to-late 30s).

Comment: @Thorgott ooh fun. I don't know a proof for freudenthal that doesn't implicitly go through Blakers-Massey.

Comment: @AndresMejia I have to slightly correct myself. The original Freudenthal Theorem proven in 1937/38 was only the case of spheres. (This also has a differential-topological interpretation, though probably not until the 50s.) The general Freudenthal Theorem was indeed first derived as a corollary to the Theorem of Blakers and Massey in 1951. However, you can also prove it without Blakers-Massey, e.g. as a corollary to James' 1955 theorem together with the theory of CW-approximations (though I'm not sure right now if this was explicit in James' papers from that period or not).

Comment: You're right about the Hurewicz theorem, thanks. What I meant with my second comment (poorly written, I see now) is that if you assume that a map $X\to Y$ is a homotopy equivalence and nullhomotopic, then automatically $X$ must be contractible (you compose the nullhomotopy and one of the homotopies of the homotopy equivalence to get the homotopy to a point). This is the case of the inclusion $X\to \Sigma X$.

Comment: @AndresMejia There's also a pretty neat proof of via the Serre spectral sequence that you can find in e.g. Davis & Kirk.

Comment: @user17786 lmaoooo very good point. I'll leave this up for the fun comments. Maybe for OP just try showing that inclusions of equators factor through the cone (up to homotopy)